# Change array to a string with commas ordered asc in php

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
$array = array(
"peter",
"john",
"maria",
"bob");
```

And now I somehow need to change the array to a string (ordered asc) like:

```
$string_with_commas = "bob, john, maria, peter";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
sort($array);
echo implode(', ', $array);
```

`sort()` will modify your array in place. If you don't want that, you have to make copy of that array.

```
<?php
$sorted_array = $array;
sort($sorted_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
sort($array)
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // email,lastname,phone

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: I'm surprised to see two upvotes on answer that is simply incorrect - `sort()` sorts inplace and only returns some sort of useless boolean value.

Comment: `?>` tags are optional and I prefer to not include them - this way you could protect yourself from whitespace just after `?>`.

Comment: Also, after your edit, `sort()` doesn't have semicolon at end.

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array("peter", "john", "maria", "bob"); 

sort($array);

$string_with_commas = implode(', ', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sort($array); //sort array in ASC order
$string = implode(', ', $array); //store as comma separated string
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
$string_with_commas = implode(', ', $array);
```